# How can I call a Stored Procedure in Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, stored-procedures

I've got the following code block within a larger javascript file. It uses an API to get the strCategoryID value and returns a list of three document names with appropriate links. works fine except that I need to sort the documents by date of input. I have a stored procedure in the SQL database that gives me what I need but I'm not sure how to make that call and populate the loop with the sorted documents. I'm modifying someone else's code and am pretty new to ajax.

```
    var list = "<ul style=\"list-style: none; text-indent: -1.2em;\" class=\"news-list\" id=\"news-" + strCategoryID + "\">";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: strParams,
    url: "/Utilities/AJAXUtilities.aspx",      
    success: function(msg){
    msg = $.createXMLDocument(msg);      
    var li_count = 0;

    $(msg).find('CONTENT_SEARCH').each(function(){

        if ($(this).find("CNT_AVAILABLE").text() == "T") {
        var title = $(this).find("CNT_TITLE").text();
        var trimtitle = title.substring(0,39);
        list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/Content/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + $(this).find("CNT_CONTENT_ID").text() + "\">" + trimtitle + "...</a></li><hr>");   
            li_count = li_count+1;
            if (li_count == 3) {
            return false;
            }
        }
    }); 

    }
    });

    list = list.concat("</ul>");
    list = list.concat("<br /><a href=\"\">View previous news releases>></a>");     
    $("#newscatlist").append(list);
    return list;
```

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are not very familiar with AJAX your easiest solution will be to modify AJAXUtilities.aspx to return the records order by what you need, in that way you don't have to deal with AJAX and/or Javascript.

Comment: That's a rabbit hole. AJAXUtilities.aspx is a custom code behind file that inherits functions from many other places.

Comment: Ok, create another ASPx page, inside that page you have to call your stored procedure and inside the ASPx you need to convert the result of that stored procedure to an XML result and return that as the new value. Remember that you should take a look at the format of the XML currently returned and mimic the same format (the order will be irrelevant). If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: Is it possible to nest ajax call like this? Can I grab the document ID, then use that to grab something else in each stage of the loop? The reason for the stored procedure is that the calls to get what I need directly don't exist in the API. The code I've included gets documents in a certain category. What I need are the last three documents entered from that category. The Input Date exists in a separate table that is indexed on the document ID which I can't get until I get the list from the category.

Comment: Definitely not optimal, but understandable in your situation. Definitely doable: